# How to avoid line breaker in the middle of a single record when spark file process

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have processed CSV file using spark which is originally exported from oracle db, When I processed that csv file, I have noticed some data mismatching problems on processed data.

after that I went through that csv file and I noticed some records lines are divided into multiple lines, (please check attached image below, see 2nd,3rd lines)

[Sample csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWRsU.png)

When I process mentioned data records by using spark,It takes a single record as two records due to line breaker in the middle of the record.I want to make that two line records as a single line record using spark.

Please help me to fixed this issue, how I avoid that line breaker and need to get that two lines as one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `multiline` option in spark. To read a CSV, you can do it like this:

```
val df = spark.read
    .option("multiline",true)
    .option("header", true)
    .csv("your_path/file.csv")
```

Comment: HI Oli, Thank you for you answer, but now I'm suffer on same issue when reading .txt and .dsv file.  Is there any way to do this on .txt and .dsv file. multiline option not work with both .txt and .dsv file

Comment: I would need sample data to help you. Txt file are not formatted and could contain anything... Also if this answer was  a solution to your first problem, consider asking a new question with as much detail as possible instead of editing this one. Dont hesitate to provide the link in comments here so that i can have a look.